# Displaying static content with angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Please forgive the newbie question; I'm just starting out with angular2. I've made it through the angular heroes demo and understand how components work, how to connect data to html, etc.

But what if I have a piece of static html that I want to display conditionally (i.e. on some pages and not others)? Do I need to create a full component, with all the imports and exports, even if there's no data model to hook it to? If not, how do I go about doing this? In angular 1, I'd just create a directive and call it, but angular2 has moved everything to components.an

**Update**
Created a component called WelcomeComponent (welcome.component.ts) and an html file (we're trying to keep all html separate in templates rather than mixing in with component code.) I registered my component in app.component.ts.

Here's the contents of welcome.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'welcome',
    templateUrl: './welcome.component.html'
})

export class WelcomeComponent{}
```

Here's welcome.component.html:

```
<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et tincidunt mi, sed porttitor justo. Donec in vehicula arcu. Sed lobortis massa in sodales feugiat. Morbi in metus tristique, volutpat nisl ut, blandit odio. Ut elit ipsum, euismod ut suscipit interdum, tristique in velit. Quisque vestibulum elementum aliquam.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { FavoritesComponent }   from './favorites.component';
import { ItemsComponent }      from './items.component';
import { ItemDetailComponent }  from './item-detail.component';
import {ItemSearchComponent} from './item-search.component';
import { ItemService }          from './item.service';
import {WelcomeComponent} from './welcome.component';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FavoritesComponent,
    ItemDetailComponent,
    ItemSearchComponent,
    ItemsComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [ ItemService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here's how I'm trying to call it in my index.html file:

```
<welcome></welcome>

  <div class="container">
    <my-app></my-app>
    <my-favorites></my-favorites>
    <hr>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
    </footer>
  </div> <!-- /container -->
```

Note that the `my-favorites` component is defined exactly the same way, and the contents of that component do display correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use a component to display the static HTML.  Start by creating a new folder in your project to hold the component.  Then create the component, which will look something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
@Component(
   selector: 'my-content',  /* this is the name that will be used in the markup */
   template: `<div>Some static content</div>`
)
export class MyContentComponent{}
```

You will then need to register this component in your app.module in the declarations section.  Now you can add the selector to any component that needs to display the static content:

```
<div>
   <my-content></my-content>
</div>
```

When you want to conditionally display the content, you can add *ngIf="showContent" to the component element ('showContent' needs to exist as a property on the hosting component).

```
<div>
   <my-content *ngIf="showContent"></my-content>
</div>
```

**Update:**

The root component of your app is AppComponent defined in markup as `<my-app>`.  All additional components need to be nested in the templates under that level.  Move the mark up from your index.html to app.component.html and it should work.

Index.html:

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

app.component.html:

```
  <welcome></welcome>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- current contents of app.component.html -->
    <my-favorites></my-favorites>
    <hr>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
    </footer>
  </div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Ugh. That's unfortunate. I was hoping there was something equivalent to a simple include file. It seems like a whole lot of trouble to create a component that contains nothing but static html.

Comment: I initially thought that as well.  However, using a component provides a declarative approach for including the content in your markup, which makes your html more readable.  The static html and component can be included in a single file, so there is no extra overhead there.  The only extra bit of work is in registering the component in the module.  I highly recommend using the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), it simplifies the task of adding and registering components.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I've been sick for three weeks. So I did as you suggested and created a component, and it's not working - there are no errors, but the contents of the component template are just not displaying. OP has been edited with new code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: Still at work, but did want to say that I'm curious as to why the `my-favorites` component works where it is in `index.html`, but the new component would not. If your solution is correct, wouldn't the `my-favorites` component be broken as well?

Comment: I was wondering that myself.  I don't know how it could work.  I tried a couple of scenarios of trying to use a component outside of the root component.  I could not get them to render outside of the root.